Why is my keyboard acting randomly weird?
A very recent issue I have is keyboard misbehaving.
The alphabet keys often do very different functions compared to their actual purpose. And it happens randomly so I have no idea when it will happen.
I've tried the xev command and it seems to be fine. When it's behaving, each of the alphabets do wildly different stuff like copy, paste, menu and other shortcuts.
For a few minutes, pressing a key could do stuff like close the app, input tab space, copy, paste and show menu instead of their actual functions.
The xev command creates a window and then asks the X server to send it events whenever anything happens.
The xev command results:

